# Magento 2: how to remove order actions elements?

Tags: magento2

Magento order actions: https://docs.magento.com/m2/2.2/ee/user_guide/sales/order-actions.html

Would like to remove some of these from the list, like "Print Credit Memos", "Print Shipping Labels"

Does anybody know how to do? Thank you

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Override `vendor/magento/module-sales/view/adminhtml/ui_component/sales_order_grid.xml`

Remove below code from it:

```
<action name="pdfcreditmemos_order">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="type" xsi:type="string">pdfcreditmemos_order</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Print Credit Memos</item>
                    <item name="url" xsi:type="url" path="sales/order/pdfcreditmemos"/>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </action>
<action name="print_shipping_label">
                <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="type" xsi:type="string">print_shipping_label</item>
                        <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Print Shipping Labels</item>
                        <item name="url" xsi:type="url" path="adminhtml/order_shipment/massPrintShippingLabel"/>
                    </item>
                </argument>
            </action>
```

Comment: Don't do this - core overrides is not the way!

Answer (score 0):

**`MassAction.php` file add action which you want to remove**

> **Step 1: Create a file `app/code/Stack/RuleBasedDiscount/view/adminhtml/ui_component/sales_order_grid.xml` and put the following code:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<listing xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
    <listingToolbar name="listing_top">
        <massaction name="listing_massaction" class="Stack\RuleBasedDiscount\Ui\MassAction">
        </massaction>
    </listingToolbar>
</listing>
```

> **Step 2: Create the file `app/code/Stack/RuleBasedDiscount/Ui/MassAction.php` and put the following code:**

```
<?php
namespace Stack\RuleBasedDiscount\Ui;

class MassAction extends \Magento\Ui\Component\MassAction
{
    private $authorization;
    public function __construct(
            \Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\ContextInterface $context,
            \Magento\Framework\AuthorizationInterface $authorization,
            array $components,
            array $data
    ) {
        $this->authorization = $authorization;
        parent::__construct($context, $components, $data);
    }

    public function prepare() {
        parent::prepare();
        $config = $this->getConfiguration();
        //if (!$this->authorization->isAllowed('Magento_Catalog::the_acl_youd_like_to_use')) {
        $allowedActions = [];
        foreach ($config['actions'] as $action) {
            if ('pdfinvoices_order' != $action['type']) { //add action which you remove
                $allowedActions[] = $action;
            }
        }
        $config['actions'] = $allowedActions;
        //}
        $this->setData('config', (array)$config);
    }
}
```

> Step 3: Run the following commands under document root:

```
php bin/magento s:up
php bin/magento cache:flush
```

Comment: Hesitating a lot between your answer and Anas Masuri answer.
Both solutions are working fine. Yours seems to be more professional. However his solution is much easier to implement and also effective. I can select as solution both answers, but choosed the other one because it's more simple. In any case, thank you very much for your answer. It's very usefull to learn Magento.

Comment: no probleam...:) happy coding..:)

Comment: As stated in the other answer, don't ever override the core!